# jquery fade in when ALL images are loaded

Tags: jquery

what's wrong with my code??

I have several images in a div, but the images are somewhat large so I dont want the user to see them loading... I want to images to display AFTER they've all loaded. ( i used >= because on the same page my logo also loads and adds +1 to the loaded images.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var loaded = $('img').load().length
   var amount_img = $("#imgcontainer img").length

   $('#imgcontainer').hide()

   $('img').load(function(){

       if (loaded >= amount_img) {
           $('#imgcontainer').delay(300).fadeIn(600)
      }

   });

});
```

Comment: Hi, if you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery load() method is used to bind an event handler to load event.

So, the statement

```
var loaded = $('img').load().length
```

will just give total number of 'img' elements in the page. Besides, this statement is executed only once and not keeping track of number of loaded images.

So, you could use a counter to keep track of images loaded.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // keep a track of number of images loaded
    var loaded = 0;
    var amount_img = $("#imgcontainer img").length;

    $('#imgcontainer').hide();

    $('#imgcontainer img').load(function () {
        // This function will be called every time an image is loaded inside imgcontainer

        // increment the counter for images loaded
        loaded++;
        if (loaded >= amount_img)
            $('#imgcontainer').delay(300).fadeIn(600);
    });

});
```

Comment: thanks man! worked. can you explain to me why you use "loaded++" (i'm learning jquery)

Comment: but you use loaded as a variable to 0. so loaded++ means 0+1; so 1. 

loaded++; 
if (loaded >= amount_img)

so what is the connection between loaded++ and the loaded in the if statement?

Comment: yes.. loaded++ is short-hand for loaded = loaded + 1. So, after first image loads, loaded becomes 1 from 0 and same way for next images loaded the loaded variable value increases..

Comment: how does jq know how much images u've allready loaded? since you just use loaded++ but not specify when the next img is loaded and where it should add up. srry for all these noob questions;)

Comment: No problem.. You may want to look into how event handlers work in JavaScript and jQuery. This may be helpful: http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/events